# PHP Date and strtotime not equal

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have met a very strange problem
the code is:

```
$timeStr = '2012-12-27 10:01:00';
$test = date('Y-m-d H:m:s',strtotime($timeStr));
echo ("timeStr : $timeStr <br/> time: $test");
```

the result is:

```
timeStr : 2012-12-27 10:01:00 
time: 2012-12-27 10:12:00
```

why they are not equal ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `m` to `i`. `m` is for months while `i` is for minutes. It should be

```
$test = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($timeStr));
```

Further reference https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Month, minute, what's the diff, right?